# Window Slider Fails When Surrounded by Form Elements

Tags: javascript, html, slider, window

Novice here. I have been struggling for several days trying to figure out why, after adding the form elements around the two slider commands and the div that is being controlled by the two slider commands, this code will not function properly. Without the form tags, the box slides up and down as it should. Add the form tags and the box will slide as if collapsing when the slideClose button is clicked but will return to the down position. Thanks, Betty

p.s. you can see the code working badly on the page: http://zillionreasons.net/twig/testarea/testslider.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div#box {
      background: #9DCEFF;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function slideOpen(el){
      var elem = document.getElementById(el);
      elem.style.transition = "height 0.2s linear 0s";
      elem.style.height = "200px";
    }
    function slideClosed(el){
      var elem = document.getElementById(el);
      elem.style.transition = "height 0.2s linear 0s";
      elem.style.height = "0px";
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <button onclick="slideClosed('box');">slideClosed</button>
    <button onclick="slideOpen('box');">slideOpen</button>
    <div id="box">Content in box 1 ...</div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<form>` tag isn't actually causing the page to break.  Its job is (normally) to submit a request to a server.  What's really happening is every time you click one of the buttons in the form, it's submitting a request to the URL you're currently on since the form's action is set to blank.

In other words, every button click is reloading the page to its default state where the box is expanded.

If you're planning on including content to submit in your collapsible `<div>`, you should move the "expand/collapse" buttons outside of the `<form>` if you don't want them to submit a request to the server, like so:

```
<button onclick="slideClosed('box');">slideClosed</button>
<button onclick="slideOpen('box');">slideOpen</button>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="box">Content in box 1 ...</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I am sure you are correct on this. Can you suggest any solutions to this problem? I appreciate your time. bb

Comment: Right now, it looks like your `form` tag doesn't have a purpose.  You would typically use that element to submit user input data to your server.  If all you're looking for is a container for your buttons, I would suggest just using a `<div>`